# How to import the full ITIS database (.sql) to PGADMIN 4

Tags: postgresql, import, pgadmin, import.sql

So I need to import the ITIS database into pdadmin4 1.5 (postgresql)

The read.me file gives me these information:

```
1. Open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to the folder where you
   unzipped the ITIS download file.

2. Enter the following:

      psql -U root -f ITIS.sql

   If your PostgreSql user is not root, substitute your user
   name for root. Also, if you are updating a remote 
   server, you will need to  add a -h <servername> to 
   the command

3. When prompted for your PostgreSql user's password, enter
   it and the load process will start.
```

The directory of the file is:

```
/Users/kostas/Desktop/itisPostgreSql063017/ITIS.sql
```

How do I open a terminal or command prompt and navigate to the folder where I unzipped the ITIS download file and how do I see if my PostgreSql user is not root?

Thanks!

Comment: How you open a terminal depends on the version of Linux that you are using.  Alt-F2 and then typing "terminal" may do it for you.  Otherwise Google "open terminal" and include the name of your distro.

Comment: hello Nielsen i do not use linux unfortunately should i do it on the mac terminal? not pgadmin?

Comment: And I don't use a Mac, but Googling "Mac open terminal" shows me that you can find likely useful information that way.